# Automatically scroll *compilation* window, beside source-buffer window

Tags: scrolling, compile-mode

I edit C in two windows side-by-side, source on left, compilation results on right.  I have <kbd>F5</kbd> bound to `recompile`.

Currently I have to do:

- <kbd>F5</kbd> to run make,
- Move to `*compilation*` buffer in right window,
- Scroll down to end of buffer,
- Move back to left window to continue to edit.

I would prefer to have all the above happen automatically by pressing [F5], without leaving the left window, so I can see the results, and continue to work.

I write C, not Lisp! ;^)

Comment: `C-h v compilation-scroll-output`

Comment: Thanks.  Was not aware of that option.

Comment: @Drew -- I could be mistaken, but the recent edits providing for a top/bottom window split do not appear to reflect the intentions of the O.P., who apparently prefers a left/right window split and simply wants the output to be automatically scrolled without visiting the compilation window (and manually going to the end of the buffer).

Comment: @lawlist: Wasn't clear to me. Retitled and tagged. Feel free to edit to make clearer. Thx.

Comment: @rpluim: Please consider posting your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

This behaviour can be controlled by `compilation-scroll-output`.

```
compilation-scroll-output is a variable defined in `compile.el'.
Its value is `first-error'
Original value was nil

Documentation:
Non-nil to scroll the *compilation* buffer window as output appears.

Setting it causes the Compilation mode commands to put point at the
end of their output window so that the end of the output is always
visible rather than the beginning.
```

See [Compilation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html#Compilation) for more info.